# How to connect interface<T> and implementation<T> in autofac .config file

Tags: dependency-injection, app-config, autofac

I have following class

```cs
namespace MyApplication.Services
{
    public class TagEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tag>{/*code goes here*/}
}
```

Now what I would like to register it in autofac using .config file based configuration:

```xml
<autofac>
    <components>
        <component type="MyApplication.Services.TagEqualityComparer, MyApplication.Services"
                   service="System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer, mscorlib" />
    </components>
</autofac>
```

I have already spent whole sunday searching for solution I failed to find any. Other registrations, non templates, works perfectly but this one refuses.
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the rest of the generic type to specify the parameter type. Something like this:

```xml
<component type="MyApplication.Services.TagEqualityComparer, MyApplication.Services"
               service="System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[[MyApplication.Services.Tag, MyApplication.Services]], mscorlib" />
```

Comment: You have saved me a few gray hairs!